# XML deserialize to different class names

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Let's say I have this imaginary xml:

```
<Schedule>
   <Month name="March">
     <Day name="Monday" />
   </Month>
   <Month name="April">
     <Day name="Tuesday" />
     <Day name="Monday" />
   </Month>
</Schedule>
```

I want to deserialize the above. However I want to deserialize this xml using a different class hierarchy because the classes Schedule, Month and Day are used somewhere else.

So for example I want to have these classes:

```
[XmlRoot( "Schedule" )
public class ParserSchedule
{
   [XmlElement("Month")]
   public List<ParserMonth> Month{ get; set; } 
}

public class ParserMonth
{
    [XmlAttribute( "name" )]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Day")]
    public List<ParserDay> Day{ get; set; } 
}

public class ParserDay
{
    [XmlAttribute( "name" )]
    public string Name{ get; set; }        
}
```

However this doesn't work. I get exceptions saying Day cannot be serialized because it does not have a default public constructor. And I guess this happens because it tries to create an instance of the Day class and not the ParserDay class..

Anyway to do this?

Comment: Have you omitted the constructor in ParsedDay in the question or you don't have one? And do you have a Day class? can you post the exact error message?

Comment: If you omit constructors then .NET generates a parameterless empty constructor by default...

Comment: Please don't put C# in the title.  That is what the tags are for.

Answer (score 6):

This is working perfectly fine for me. You must have some other problem or didn't paste your code correctly/completely.

```
void Main()
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ParserSchedule));
    var xml = @"<Schedule>
   <Month name=""March"">
     <Day name=""Monday"" />
   </Month>
   <Month name=""April"">
     <Day name=""Tuesday"" />
     <Day name=""Monday"" />
   </Month>
</Schedule>";

    using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var schedule = (ParserSchedule)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        schedule.Dump(); // LINQPad method to dump object to debug
    }
}

[XmlRoot("Schedule")]
public class ParserSchedule
{
   [XmlElement("Month")]
   public List<ParserMonth> Month{ get; set; } 
}

public class ParserMonth
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Day")]
    public List<ParserDay> Day{ get; set; } 
}

public class ParserDay
{
    [XmlAttribute( "name" )]
    public string Name{ get; set; }        
}

public class Day
{
    private Day() {} // new Day() should fail to compile
}
```

Coding style note: You really should call your members that return collection type as plural `public List<ParserDay> Days{ get; set; }` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this ?

```
[XmlRoot("Schedule")]
public class ParserSchedule
{
    [XmlElement("ParserMonth")]
    public ParserMonth[] Months { get; set; } 
}

public class ParserMonth
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ParserDay")]
    public ParserDay[] Days { get; set; } 
}

public class ParserDay
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
[XmlRootAttribute( ElementName ="DesiredElement")]
```